# Как преобразовать list comprehension на развернутую запись цикла for в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Нужно транспонировать матрицу 2х3 только через цикл for (не используя готовые библиотеки). Имеется такая короткая запись:

```
print([[arr4[j][i] for j in range(len(arr4))] for i in range(len(arr4[0]))])
```

Как можно это правильно развернуть?

Comment: Что ещё за 'петля'? И у вас и так цикл for в вашем генераторе. Что мешает его развернуть?

Comment: В том и вопрос: как его правильно развернуть?

Comment: Разве ответ не подходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно только записать циклы из генератора списков, начиная с конца, и добавить явный объект списка:

```
arr4 = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
arrt = []
for i in range(len(arr4[0])):
    arrt.append([])
    for j in range(len(arr4)):
        arrt[-1].append(arr4[j][i])
print(arrt)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно без добавления нового списка?

Comment: Да, просто печатайте элемент `print(arr4[j][i], end = ' ')` , а вместо `arrt.append([])` перевод строки